# A class with __slots__ defined inherits from a class without __slots__ defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code in Python 2.7:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     __slots__ = tuple()
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.x = 1
>>> b.y = 2
```

Does that mean the `__slots__` in the subclass `B` is basically useless, because it does not prevent dynamic attribute creation?

Comment: Related: [Python: How does inheritance of \_\_slots\_\_ in subclasses actually work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1816483)

Comment: And you should **not** rely on `__slots__` preventing dynamic attributes. That's not what `__slots__` are *for*. They are meant to limit the amount of memory instances require.

Comment: Hi, @jonsharpe. I have a followup question after reading the doc. The use of \__slots__ is to save memory, which is achieved by removing the dictionary \__dict__ for attribute storage. If the space allocated for the attributes that're assigned to \__slots__ is bigger than the space saved, does that mean setting \__slots__ is meaningless?

Comment: That doesn't make sense; give that the same attribute values would be stored in the dictionary `__dict__` as you're storing using `__slots__`, how could that *ever* be the case? You're *always* saving the space that the dictionary itself would have taken up. Also note that I don't get notified if you spell my username wrongly!

Comment: A dictionary object over-allocates and will *always* take up more space than the slots.

Comment: @jon but you always get notified for comments on your own posts. Which is why your name isn't even available for auto-completion and got misspelled in the first place :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, if the OP had commented on the answer I would have been pinged. Is autocomplete not available for editors' names, even though they're eligible for notifications?

Comment: @jon: Ah, missed that this is *question* (I am on mobile at the moment). No, editor names are not available for auto-completion either.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I got the idea now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> When inheriting from a class without `__slots__`, the `__dict__`
>   attribute of that class will always be accessible, so a `__slots__`
>   definition in the subclass is meaningless.