# How can I force subclasses to have __slots__?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, metaprogramming, slots

I have a class with [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

```
class A:
    __slots__ = ('foo',)
```

If I create a subclass without specifying `__slots__`, the subclass will have a `__dict__`:

```
class B(A):
    pass

print('__dict__' in dir(B))  # True
```

Is there any way to prevent `B` from having a `__dict__` without having to set `__slots__ = ()`?

Comment: Background: I'll be instantiating *a lot* of `A` objects, so I'm using `__slots__` to reduce memory consumption. `A` is also sitting at the top of a large class hierarchy with many mixins and subclasses, so I would like to avoid writing `__slots__ = ()` in every single subclass.

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816483/python-how-does-inheritance-of-slots-in-subclasses-actually-work ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I don't see how that answers my question - I understand how `__slots__` interacts with inheritance, and I want to find a way to change how it works.

Comment: If you only want to spare memory, is it a solution for you to just dynamically empty `__dict__` like `B.__dict__ = ()`when instantiating?

Comment: @Markus For my specific use case? Maybe. But let's stick to answering the question I asked. We want this thread to be useful for other readers as well, after all.

Comment: Just to be clear: the subclasses never add some instance attributes? Or to put it differently, do you need an opt-out mechanism for adding the dict or extending slots?

Comment: @MSeifert No, there might be some subclasses that add new instance attributes. This question is only about those subclasses that don't define `__slots__` at all - those classes should default to having `__slots__` set to `()`. Classes that *do* define `__slots__` should be left alone. There's also no need for an opt-out mechanism because that already exists: a class that wants a dict can just set `__slots__ = ('__dict__',)`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Okay thanks for the clarification. It wasn't obvious from the question so I thought I ask. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer of [@AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580173/5393381) is almost correct. I think `__prepare__` and a metaclass is indeed the way this can be solved quite easily.

Just to recap:

- If the namespace of the class contains a `__slots__` key after the class body is executed then the class will use `__slots__` instead of `__dict__`.
- One can inject names into the namespace of the class *before* the class body is executed by using `__prepare__`.

So if we simply return a dictionary containing the key `'__slots__'` from `__prepare__` then the class will (if the `'__slots__'` key isn't removed again during the evaluation of the class body) use `__slots__` instead of `__dict__`.
Because `__prepare__` just provides the initial namespace one can easily override the `__slots__` or remove them again in the class body.

So a metaclass that provides `__slots__` by default would look like this:

```py
class ForceSlots(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metaclass, name, bases, **kwds):
        # calling super is not strictly necessary because
        #  type.__prepare() simply returns an empty dict.
        # But if you plan to use metaclass-mixins then this is essential!
        super_prepared = super().__prepare__(metaclass, name, bases, **kwds)
        super_prepared['__slots__'] = ()
        return super_prepared
```

So every class and subclass with this metaclass will (by default) have an empty `__slots__` in their namespace and thus create a "class with slots" (except the `__slots__` are removed on purpose).

Just to illustrate how this would work:

```py
class A(metaclass=ForceSlots):
    __slots__ = "a",

class B(A):  # no __dict__ even if slots are not defined explicitly
    pass

class C(A):  # no __dict__, but provides additional __slots__
    __slots__ = "c",

class D(A):  # creates normal __dict__-based class because __slots__ was removed
    del __slots__

class E(A):  # has a __dict__ because we added it to __slots__
    __slots__ = "__dict__",
```

Which passes the tests mentioned in AKZs answer:

```py
assert "__dict__" not in dir(A)
assert "__dict__" not in dir(B)
assert "__dict__" not in dir(C)
assert "__dict__" in dir(D)
assert "__dict__" in dir(E)
```

And to verify that it works as expected:

```py
# A has slots from A: a
a = A()
a.a = 1
a.b = 1  # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'b'

# B has slots from A: a
b = B()  
b.a = 1
b.b = 1  # AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'b'

# C has the slots from A and C: a and c
c = C()
c.a = 1
c.b = 1  # AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'b'
c.c = 1

# D has a dict and allows any attribute name
d = D()  
d.a = 1
d.b = 1
d.c = 1

# E has a dict and allows any attribute name
e = E()  
e.a = 1
e.b = 1
e.c = 1
```

As pointed out in a comment (by [Aran-Fey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/aran-fey)) there is a difference between `del __slots__` and adding `__dict__` to the `__slots__`:

> There's a minor difference between the two options: `del __slots__` will give your class not only a `__dict__`, but also a `__weakref__` slot.

Comment: It's already been said in a comment on the question, but I think it's worth pointing out that `del __slots__` isn't the only way to give your class a dict: You can also explicitly create a slot for the dict, like `__slots__ = ('__dict__',)`. There's a minor difference between the two options: `del __slots__` will give your class not only a `__dict__`, but also a `__weakref__` slot.

Comment: I found that it also works just by overriding `type.__new__` in the metaclass instead of `__prepare__`, though the fact that this works at all surprises me.

Answer (score 2):

How about a metaclass like this and [the `__prepare__()` hook](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace)?

```py
import sys


class InheritSlots(type):
    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwds):
        # this could combine slots from bases, I guess, and walk the base hierarchy, etc
        for base in bases:
            if base.__slots__:
                kwds["__slots__"] = base.__slots__
                break
        return kwds


class A(metaclass=InheritSlots):
    __slots__ = ("foo", "bar", "quux")


class B(A):
    pass


assert A.__slots__
assert B.__slots__ == A.__slots__
assert "__dict__" not in dir(A)
assert "__dict__" not in dir(B)

print(sys.getsizeof(A()))
print(sys.getsizeof(B()))
```

For some reason, this still does print `64, 88` – maybe an inherited class's instances are always a little heavier than the base class itself?

Comment: Shouldn't the slots in child classes _not_ have the same things as their parent? From the docs: "unless they also define `__slots__` (which should only contain names of any _additional_ slots)."

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm not a big fan of the implementation. Like aneroid said, the child class shouldn't duplicate its parent's `__slots__` - the correct solution would be to set it to an empty tuple. And I think it's quite questionable of your `__prepare__` method to turn keyword arguments into class attributes. I've opted to implement the logic in the metaclass's `__new__` instead, with a simple `cls_dict.setdefault('__slots__', ())`.

Comment: That's apparently how `__prepare__` should work, that kwds thing. (I actually hadn't used `__prepare__` before this, I just looked it up in the manual and relevant PEP.)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure to be honest. But if it is, I wouldn't do it manually - I'd just make a `super().__prepare__` call.